Distribution of shares in 2 seemingly similar problems gives different results - Why?
Note: This is not a homework.
Consider the following 2 problems:
Problem 1
A company with total number of shares A. This company has 2 share holders p1 and s.
p1 has number of shares (B). s has $B/2$ shares.
What are the shares of each of the two partners in terms of A?
Answer:
We have 2 partners.
p1 gets $2A/3$ shares and the other partner gets $A/3$ shares.

Problem 2
A company with total number of shares A. This company has 3 share holders p1, p2 and s.
p1 and p2 has the same number of shares (B). s has $B/2$ shares.
partner p2 decides to leave the company, and gives away his shares equally to the other two partners.
What are the shares of the remaining 2 partners in terms of A.
Answer:
We have 2 partners.
p1 gets $3A/5$ shares and the other partner gets $2A/5$ shares.
My question
In problem 2, after p2 leaves, I consider that the problem becomes essential equivillent to problem 1. However, each problem has its own unique solutions. I expected that both problems would have the same result but this is not the case.
Could someone explain why the answers differ or what is the cursial difference between the two problems.  Thank you.

After the redistribution, it is no longer the case that $s$ has half as many shares as $p_1$.

Why don't you try to work it out algebraically to convince yourself ?

@lulu, excellent point. So the starting condition for problem 1 is not the same after re-distribution in problem 2. Thank you.

@trueblueanil, well, I did and that is how I got the answers. I was having an issue justifying the result.

Oh, you wanted an intuitive esplanation of the algebraic result, ok.

To see they are not the same problem, suppose the company has $A=150$ shares in total in both cases.

In problem 1, $B=100$ and $P_1$ gets $100$ while $S$ gets $50$.

In problem 2, $B=60$ and $P_1$ starts with $60$, $P_2$ starts with $60$, while $S$ starts with $30$.  If $P_2$ gives $30$ to $P_1$ and $P_2$ gives $30$ to $S$, then $P_1$ ends with $60+30=90$ while $S$ ends with $30+30=60$; this is not the same as problem $1$.


To get a version of problem 2 to match problem 1, you need $P_2$ to give shares away in the ratio $B:\frac{B}{2}$, i.e. $2:1$ or $40:20$, to match the original ratio. So if instead $P_2$ gives $40$ to $P_1$ and $P_2$ gives $20$ to $S$, then $P_1$ ends with $60+40=100$ while $S$ ends with $30+20=50$, as in problem 1.

Thank you for taking the time to write it down. Together with @lulu comment, I can see the light (or at least so I think :).
